# Mouse middle click stoped working

Tags: mouse, mouse-wheel

I have been using the middle click copy/paste up until today. Actually I was using it up until just about two hours ago. Nothing updated and I haven't installed anything before that time that would make it stop working (I haven't installed anything since two days ago). My system froze up and I had to restart it and now it's not working.

I was wondering if there's a way to check and see what went wrong? Or if there's a way to get my middle click back? I can't middle click anywhere, not in Firefox to go to a new tab, not to close a tab, not to paste, not in Empathy to paste, not anywhere as far I can find.

I use an Acer Aspire One and dual booting Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows 7 Starter.
I have a usb mouse and a usb keyboard.

If more information is needed let me know. I would greatly enjoy a little bit of help here.

EDIT: followed answer instructions and using `xev` I verified that my mouse is broken.

Comment: yeah, that works. different mouse solved the problem. thanks for that. 'xev' worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I converted my comment to an answer so you can accept it and I get all the nice internet points.

Comment: just for the record i have this same problem and if people would have been able to help I would have appreciated.  There are 10 closed questions about mouse wheel click not working and no pointers to valid answers.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe your mouse is broken? You could run `xev` in a terminal and middle click inside the little window that it opens. You should see a `ButtonPress event` and `ButtonRelease event` (only read the first words of each paragraph, the rest doesn't matter here).

Comment: What if you don't see any event? Does that mean that the mouse is broken, or could it be a driver issue?

Comment: No event seen in xev indicates hardware problem, try to replicate it in a different machine. xev is quite noisy testing the wheel so grepping for Button might help   xev| grep -A2 Button